# Istgame package, error when trying to replicate a dynamic game

Tags: packages

I have tried to replicate a dynamic game with incomplete information but I am having a lot of problems creating and generating the code, please help.

This is the procedure I have done, it looks a bit similar but I would like it to look a bit more organized or the nodes a bit larger so that the game actions can be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\istroot(0){FUTURO}
\istb{No \quad entrar}[above left]{(0,4)}
\istb<missing> 
\istb {Nicho \quad G}[below left]
\istb<missing> \istb<missing>
\istb{Nicho \quad P}[right]
\endist
\istroot(2)(0-6)
\istb{Nicho \quad G}[above left]{(1,1)}
\istb{Nicho \quad P}[above right]{(-3,-1)}
\endist
\istroot(1)(0-3)
\istb{Nicho \quad G}[above left]{(-6,-4)}
\istb{Nicho \quad P}[above right]{(-1,3)}
\endist
\xtInfoset(1)(2){PASADO}
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty of translating your Spanish language writeup into English. Feel free to adapt or revert.

Comment: @Topacio Please show what you tried. I'm sure we can then help you fix any remaining problems with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have already resolved the question I had, now the code looks like this:
My only doubt now is that when I run it in TexMaker, the branches that should be invisible due to the "missing" do not become invisible. But when I run it in Overleaf it works and looks good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\xtdistance{30mm}{20mm}
\istroot(0){FUTURO}
\istb{No \quad entrar}[above left]{(0,4)}
\istb<missing> 
\istb {Nicho \quad G}[below left]
\istb<missing> \istb<missing>
\istb{Nicho \quad P}[right]
\endist
\xtdistance{30mm}{20mm}
\istroot(2)(0-6)
\istb{Nicho \quad G}[above left]{(1,1)}
\istb{Nicho \quad P}[above right]{(-3,-1)}
\endist
\istroot(1)(0-3)
\istb{Nicho \quad G}[above left]{(-6,-4)}
\istb{Nicho \quad P}[above right]{(-1,3)}
\endist
\xtInfoset(1)(2){PASADO}
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: now I used \istbm instead of \istb<missing> it worked. However, if anyone has a better one, I would like to see their procedure and the result. Thank you very much

Comment: You should probably ask a followup question and link this one. There isn't a good way for people to answer a question asked in an answer and people looking for questions to answer are less likely to find it.